# Rails create object has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My models

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :outfits
  has_many :products, through: :outfits
end

class Outfit < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :collection
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :outfits
  has_many :collections, through: :outfits
end
```

I want to save product in collection  model

so one collection can have few product in it

How can i do it? i'm a bit struggle with it

it have tried something like this

```
p = Product.find_by_code('0339').id

p.collections.create(product_id:p1)
```

but i guess i'm wrong

Comment: Could you write out the relationship you want to model? It would make it easier to understand. For example, do collections have many outfits, and outfits have many products, but products only have one outfit?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt my main goal is to have one `product` in many `collections`

Comment: And what relationship to outfits play in this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt i want to keep many `products` in many `collections` through `outfit` if its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're chaining through a `through` collection you don't need to reference the parent's id since that is known.

Instead of:

```
p = Product.find_by_code('0339').id # NOTE that you have an 'id' not an object here
p.collections.create(product_id:p1) # you can't call an association on the id
```

Build the association between two existing models (I'm assuming you have other fields in your models; I'm using `name` as an example).

```
p = Product.find_by(code: '0339')
c = Collection.find_by(name: 'Spring 2016 Clothing')
o = Outfit.new(name: 'Spring 2016 Outfit', product: p, collection: c)
o.save!
```

Assuming `p` and `c` exist and assuming `o` passes validation then you now have an assocaition between one product and one collection using a new outfit as the join table.

```
p.reload
p.collections.count # => 1

c.reload
c.products.count # => 1
```

Comment: `reload` probably wasn't necessary; in this test I was just ensuring that building the `Outfit` instance would be reflected immediately in the new queries